# When would redux getState be useful

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand whats the point of using getState() when i can get the state of something like this

```
return{
  ...state
}
```

take for example this code. I'm able to retrieve data, post data, etc.

When will using getState() be useful ?

```
const initialState = {
    images:[],
    likedByuser: false
}
export default  (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_IMAGES:
            return{
                ...state,

            }
        case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                images:action.images
            }
        case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
            return{
                ...state
            }
        case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
            const newImage = action.data
            return {           
                images:[
                    {
                        id: newImage[0].id,
                        user:{
                            username:newImage[0].user.username
                        },
                        comments:{
                        comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                        },
                        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                    },
                    ...state.images, // pass the previous images, 
                ]   
            }
            ....
```

Comment: `getState()` is ideally when you want to get a state any where with store and without connect and mapToState

Comment: ok i see. thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you'll use `getState()` inside of an action creator, where you want access to the entire/partial redux state. The state inside of the reducer **isn't the complete redux *state***. Instead, **the reducer is only handling that which you've defined in *initialState*.**

For example...

postActions.js

```
export const postToArticle = props => (dispatch, getState) => {
   const state = getState(); // access to entire redux tree

  ...etc

};
```

---

When you set up your state, ideally you'll separate each piece of the state as in its own reducer. For example, one of my reducers handles just `messages` and another handles just `user` authentication:

**serverMessageReducer.js**

```
import * as types from "../types";

export const initialState = {
    message: "",
    show: false,
    type: "",
};

/**
 * @function serverMessageReducer
 * @param {object} state - an object containing success/error/info server messages.
 * @param {object} action - type and payload to be reduced.
 * @returns {object} - messages state.
 */
const serverMessageReducer = (state = initialState, { payload, type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case types.MESSAGE_HIDE:
            return { ...state, show: false };
        case types.MESSAGE_RESET:
            return { ...state, message: "", type: "" };
        case types.MESSAGE_SET:
            return { message: payload.message, show: true, type: payload.type };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default serverMessageReducer;
```

**userAuthReducer.js**

```
import * as types from "../types";

export const initialState = {
    id: "",
    email: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    role: "",
};

/**
 * @function authReducer
 * @param {object} state - an object containing current user session state.
 * @param {object} action - type and payload to be reduced.
 * @returns {object} - user session state.
 */
const authReducer = (state = initialState, { payload, type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case types.USER_SIGNIN:
            return { ...state, ...payload };
        case types.USER_SIGNOUT:
            return initialState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default authReducer;
```

---

So, say if I needed access to two separate pieces of state, then I can either pass it to the action creator via `mapStateToProps` or I can retrieve it from within the action creator via `getState()`.

---

On a side note, your `GET_IMAGES` and `UPLOAD_IMAGE` cases don't need to be defined within the reducer, since they're just returning what's already in state. If you set up your `switch/case` statement with a `default`, then it'll already be handled:

```
const initialState = {
    images:[],
    likedByuser: false
};

export default  (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                images:action.images
            }
        case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
            const newImage = action.data
            return {           
                images:[
                    {
                        id: newImage[0].id,
                        user:{
                            username:newImage[0].user.username
                        },
                        comments:{
                        comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                        },
                        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                    },
                    ...state.images, // pass the previous images, 
                ]   
            }

          ...etc

        default: return state
    }
```